# Updating DB entry through controller not connecting with foreign key? ModelState invalid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

this is how the controller looks like

```
public ActionResult Edit()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Car _car)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        entities.Entry(_car).State = EntityState.Modified;
        entities.SaveChanges();
        RedirectToAction("Stock");
    }
    return View(_car);
}
```

the page itself is pretty much the "Edit" template with just a different redirect at the bottom.

this is the `Car` class

```
public partial class Car
{
    public Car()
    {
        this.Orders = new HashSet<Order>();
    }

    public int CarID { get; set; }
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public decimal Daily_Cost { get; set; }
    public decimal Late_Fee { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public string Gear { get; set; }
    public int Mileage { get; set; }
    public bool Available { get; set; }
    public string Registration { get; set; }
    public int Location { get; set; }
    public string Picture { get; set; }

    public virtual Branch Branch { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

I'm not exactly sure what's causing the ModelState to be invalid but when I look at the object at runtime the only thing I see that I think is wrong, is `Branch` is null.

`Branch` is in a relationship in the db with `Location`. `Location` is foreign key and `Branch` is primary key (in the DB it's `BranchID` but I don't think that's relevant)

Comment: You are receiving the error because Branch is null.  You might be able to fix this by adding public int BranchId as a property in your model.

Comment: @drneel like a property of `car`?

Comment: Correct.  I'm not sure if it will work, I don't normally directly reference my entities as controller models

Comment: @drneel adding BranchID didn't work so i tried to add `Branch` to the Edit page, didn't work either

Comment: I usually have a view model that I use to look up the entity and then map everything from the view model to the entity.  You could try to do something similar...  it would be like _db.cars.find(id).include<branch>() or something similar